# Why below .htaccess code not works correctly

Tags: .htaccess

Below code is to make my url look pretty

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^info/(.*)$" "/detail.php?id=$1" [L,NC]
```

detail.php will retrieve data from database based on ID we send to it, but page will be display as it has no css and JS file
it displays as below:

[image]

While it should be like this
[image]

Comment: The problem is most probably with the use of "relative" client-side URLs. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^info/(.*)$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And add before your CSS & JS links this: http://example.com/your_files.css

The problem is from **your links!** Just add **domain** before them, and everything will work :)

Or just add this to your `<head>` tag : (Specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page)

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

> See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp), it's **the solution** to your problem :)

Comment: Same problem, this is how Css file referenced in detail page    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Show me what do you get by clicking to your js or CSS links?

Comment: by clicking to many time,it will continually add css/style.css to the end of url,,,,view-source:http://localhost/info/css/css/css/css/css/css/css/css/style.css

Comment: See my Answer and try please ? :)

Comment: The problem is from your links! Just add domain before them, and everything will work :)

Comment: But is there any other solutions, because I have to change all my Relative Paths to Absolute Pathes

Comment: And about your code! not forget to verify in your PHP code if **GET id** is **numeric**.

Comment: This is the best solution, other solutions will increase the load on the site, and I recommend adding the domain, and you can make it variable like: `$domain = "example.com";`

Comment: it works but not for my case, Because I also have relative path images in multi folders , So its not good solution for my case

Comment: When I use PHP **without any framework**, this is my way of creating shortcuts in the links and solving the CSS problem, If my answer is helpful, please make my answer is the solution. Thanks ;)